# C# call value from datagrid of selected row

Tags: c#, button, datagridview

I have created a C# datagrid that is called from SQL query , now i am a bit stuck i want to call the value at postion 2 ("Gebruikersnaam") from the button ("Verstuur reminder").

Note the button is added after the data is called from sql with

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btn.HeaderText = "reminder";
            btn.Text = "Verstuur reminder";
            btn.Name = "reminder";
            btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
```

i have tried to get the index and row but nothing returns an actual value

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show((e.RowIndex+1)+"Rij "+(e.ColumnIndex+1)+"Column ");
        }
```

The required behavior is when a user clicks the button "Verstuur reminder" the program calls the value of "Gebruikersnaam" and uses this value later in the program.

Picture DataGrid
[image: Picture DataGrid]

Comment: When does The code you shared for showing message box is execute?

Comment: If e.ColumnIndex != 0 then what value you have in e.ColumnIndex?

Comment: @Chetan this is an on click event

Comment: @Chetan the value i get by clicking on the first button is row 1, Column 1 second one is row 2 Coulmn 1

Comment: What grid event are you using to execute the second snippet of code? And “why” is the code adding “1” to the row and column indexes?  … `(e.RowIndex+1)+"Rij "+(e.ColumnIndex+1)+"Column ");` … ? …

Comment: You can probably do something like this dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Gebruikersnaam"].Value to get the value of the Gebruikersnaam Column on the current row that you have pressed the button.

Comment: @JohnG The buttons row is added by code so is not in the dataset , the index of that button is 0 so 0+1 is the starting point  of the aqtual dataset.

Comment: @Izanagi ok that was simple that did work for me , thanks

Comment: _"The buttons row is added by code so is not in the dataset , the index of that button is 0 so 0+1 is the starting point of the aqtual dataset."_ ... ? ... it is irrelevant that the button is NOT part of the data set. Again... What event are you calling this code with?

Comment: If you are saying that the button column is at column index 0… then the `if` statement should look something like… `if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) { MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString()); }` …

Comment: In addition, have you considered adding the button column AFTER the grids data source has been set? This would avoid having to use column indexes that do not appear correct given the grids current column display order… in other words, the column indexes would be that same as the picture shows.